# Extracting a JSON value from an external API with PHP

Tags: php, json

How can I get `videoId` (selected on image) in PHP? It's my code and it's not working (I'm talking about `echo [...]`). It returns:

> Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in /home/****/public_html/ytshots/index.php on line 38

```
$url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?maxResults=4&type=video&order=date&part=snippet&forUsername=MKL&key=****';
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$characters = json_decode($data);

echo $characters->$items['videoId'];
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `$characters` represents the JSON object in your image, you're looking for the following:

```
echo $characters->items[0]->id->videoId;
```

This is because `items` is a **key** in the JSON array. `items` is actually an **array**, and you're trying to access the first index of it, so you need `[0]`. Then you need to target the next key down, which is **`id`**, not `videoID`. Then once you are inside the `id` object, you can access `videoID` as another key.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: It's working! Thank you very much :)! Sorry, but I can't give the vote for your answer :(.

Comment: @TomaszChwicewski - you can accept the answer though.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear this solution appears to have helped you. Once you've confirmed this solution solves your problem, please don't forget to mark the solution as correct by clicking on the grey check below the vote buttons -- this removes it from the 'Unanswered Questions' queue, and awards reputation to both the question asker and question answerer. You'll be able to do that 15 minutes after asking any question. Of course, in saying that, you are under no obligation to mark my answer (or any other answer) as correct, though it does help to keep things on StackOverflow flowing smoothly :)